# Relative paths in C

Tags: c, relative-path

I have a C program that uses some resources located in the same directory as the executable. When I execute the program from a random working directory (not the directory where the program is located) the resources don't load, because the relative path I use in the code is not the path where the executable is. How can I solve this nicely?

Comment: Well, use absolute path?

Comment: @KingsIndian: how does he know where the executable will end up? Rsources are relative to the exe folder, no?

Comment: Well, that certainly a answer but then the user can't change to directory of the program, unless I hard code all path with some sort of Windows API function to retrieve the actual absolute path...

Comment: @DervinThunk Hardcoding with relative paths and then executing from other directories is the problem. Why would the location of exe matter as long as the resources have absolute path?

Comment: In Windows, there are (apparently) ways to locate resources relative to the location of the executable. In Unix-like systems, I don't think there's any clean way to do this -- but then Unix programs typically don't use the location of an executable to find other resources. They typically use absolute paths configured when the application is built and/or environment variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the path of the directory that contains the resources to the program as an argument and either:

- change the current directory of the process to the directory ([`chdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) on Unix and [`SetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on Windows), or
- construct absolute paths to the resources

---

If it is Windows, as the comment on the question suggests, you can obtain the path of the `exe` using [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), extract the directory from it and avoid having to provide an argument to the program. Then either of two options listed would allow the program to be executed from anywhere and still locate its resources.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone happening upon this old question in the future as I just did:

The program (at least in linux) keeps the command it was called by as the first argument of `int main` argument list.

e.g.
In this example we will drill down a couple of directories to get to our program, resulting in the following call command `user@PC:~$ ./foo/bar/awesome_program.x86_64`.
The program (code below) will print `./foo/bar/awesome_program.x86_64`.
Since we have that string as a variable, it should be rather simple to construct relative paths from it, only replacing the end of that string with paths relative to the executable.

working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("calling path: %s\n", argv[0]);

    return 0;
}
```